# Analog of DependencyPropertyDescriptor (wpf) in Avalonia Ui?

Tags: avaloniaui, avalonia

How do I implement the same behavior(wpf) in Avalonia?

```
var leftDescriptor= DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(Canvas.LeftProperty, typeof(SomeObject));
    leftDescriptor.AddValueChanged(this, OnCanvasLeftChanged);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just subscribe to changes like this:
`Canvas.LeftProperty.Changed.Subscribe(OnCanvasLeftChanged);`

Make sure to import the System namespace, otherwise the relevant extension method from `System.ObservableExtensions` won't be found by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!